# Why are the following array operations illegal?

Tags: c, arrays

The expressions `x++;` and `x*2;` are reported as *illegal*. Compiler generates error. However, in case of `x+1;` there's no error reported.

Can anyone help me understand why the particular expressions are illegal? Or, in other way, why the addition is legal?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{ 
   int x[]={1,2,3,4,5};
   x++;
   x+1; 
   x*2;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try them and find out?

Comment: @InternetAussie i tried x++,it is illegal.wanted the explanation

Comment: Make that your question then!

Comment: x is an *array* so you can't increment it, there is no * operator for *arrays*, but you can add 1 as your array decays to pointer and gives you access to pointer arithmetic.

Comment: GCC gives an error :         error: lvalue required as increment operand
            x++;

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès _as your array decays to pointer_ - where?

Comment: Well, while the particular question is worded poorly, the query _may_ have some merit. Not all the books define/describe these tricky things in detailed and understandable way. Just my two cents.

Comment: @KeineLust as an operand of `+`.

Comment: @KeineLust in `x+1`

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès , Quentin , I see ... decays but do nothing with the result, is a NOOP isn't it?

Comment: Hello sir @YuHao, is there a particular reason you reverted my rollback?

Comment: @SouravGhosh not quite sure why the tag "multiplication" is necessary here.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Probably because, the properties of multiplication operand is in discussion here? I'm open to suggestions, thought. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is an array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you need to understand **how and when** the operators are allowed. Let's see one by one.

Quoting from `C11`,

- ***`++`, Postfix increment,  chapter §6.5.2.3***

  > The operand of the postfix increment or decrement operator shall have atomic, qualified,
  >   or unqualified real or pointer type, and shall be a modifiable lvalue.
- ***`+`, Additive operator, chapter §6.5.6***

  > For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a
  >   pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is
  >   equivalent to adding 1.)
- ***`*`, Multiplicative operator, chapter §6.5.5***

  > Each of the operands shall have arithmetic type. [...]

Now, in your usage

- `x++;` --> `x` is not a modifiable lvalue, it is of "array type". This causes error.
- `x+1;` --> Satisfies the requirement <sup>see notes for array decay</sup>, hence valid.
- `x*2`; --> `x` is not arithmetic type (its'a *pointer type*), hence invalid.

---

*Additional notes:* (all emphasis mine)

- "Modifiable lvalue:"

  Quoting chapter §6.3.2.1,

  > An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially
  >   designates an object; [...] A **modifiable lvalue** is an lvalue that
  >   **does not have array type**, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified
  >   type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including,
  >   recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified
  >   type.
- "Arithmetic Type:"

  Quoting §6.2.5,

  > Integer and floating types are collectively called arithmetic types. [...]
- "Array decay:"

  Quoting §6.3.2.1,

  > Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
  >   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has
  >   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
  >   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.** [...]

Answer (score 5):

Among these three statements

```
x++;
x+1; 
x*2;
```

there is only two statements are illegal. This statement

```
x+1;
```

is correct. In this case in the expression the array designator is converted to pointer to its first element.

Multiplicative operators are not defined for pointers. So this statement

```
x*2;
```

is illegal.

Arrays are non-modifiable lvalues.  You may not change an array designator. So this statement

```
x++;
```

is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `x` is an **array** and you cannot modify the address of an array. It is illegal in C.

**GCC** compiler gives an error :

```
 In function 'main':
5:5: error: lvalue required as increment operand
    x++;
     ^
7:5: error: invalid operands to binary * (have 'int *' and 'int')
    x*2;
```